# Search filter not working in Rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

A search filter was working fine in this and there's a need to filter out the list with a user-defined distance and for that, a get function is written. Now, the filter is gone. It is appearing when I comment out the get functions.

```
class ServiceProviderList(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = ProfileCompletion.objects.all()
        serializer_class=ProfilecompletioneSerializer
        filterset_class=SnippetFilter  
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter]
        filterset_fields = ['fullname', 'category','departments','services']
        search_fields = ['fullname', 'category__name','departments__dept_name','services__service_name']
   
    def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs): 
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
        Dist = request.GET.get("distance")
        rad=float(Dist)
        radius=rad/111
        print(radius)
        query = ProfileCompletion.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(customer.location,radius))
        serializer = ProfilecompletioneSerializer(query,many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        return Response({"message":"Listed Successfully.","data":data})
```

Comment: Same with pagination also. which is called globally in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lossing all the functionalities because you are overriding the wrong method. Instead of `get()` method, you should override `get_queryset` method:

```
class ServiceProviderList(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = ProfileCompletion.objects.all()
        serializer_class=ProfilecompletioneSerializer
        filterset_class=SnippetFilter  
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter]
        filterset_fields = ['fullname', 'category','departments','services']
        search_fields = ['fullname', 'category__name','departments__dept_name','services__service_name']
   
    def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs):
        qset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
        dist = self.request.GET.get("distance")
        rad=float(dist)
        radius=rad/111
        return qset.filter(location__distance_lte=(customer.location,radius))
```

Comment: get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

This is the error I'm getting

Comment: Sorry for that. It should be fixed now

Comment: it worked and the search filters appeared. but search and filtering is not working now.

Comment: Fixed it. But had to call the distance from another model instead of giving it as dynamic.